# android tablet emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I want to develop application for `Android tablet`. But I am unable to create a `tablet size emulator`. Emulator size should be `1024x600 (WSVGA)` but there is no option to make tablet size emulator in default skin size in sdk2.2 as well as sdk 2.3.
**Then How to create tablet size emulator?** However i have tried to make tablet size emulator manually putting the screen size `600x1024` in screen resolution. But this emulator is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can download the Galaxy Tab Emulator from the "Android SDK and AVD Manager".  Under "Available Packages", "Third party Ad-ons", "Samsung"

Comment: This is definitely a better idea, especially when one is developing for API 8. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 21):

Set the resolution you want while defining the AVD:

[image]

Comment: this avd is for which tablets?

Comment: any one that matches these properties

Comment: This seems to create an emulator without the skin that includes the keyboard and critical buttons: back, menu, etc.

Comment: Usually tablets have no keyboard nor buttons

Comment: You can add the keyboard support in the Hardware options

Answer (score 0):

If you create emulator with tablet-specific Android version (e.g. 3.2) then it has tablet UI by default.