# Do I need screenshots for both 7-inch and 10-inch Android tablets?

Tags: android, screenshot

I am in charge of launching my app on Google Play. My question is: Do I need to upload screenshots for both the 7-inch and the 10-inch tablets in order for the app to show up on the Play store on the tablet? For example, if I only have screenshots for the 7-inch tablet, will the app still appear in the Play store on a 10-inch tablet? Conversely, if I only have the screenshots for the 7-inch tablet and not the 10-inch tablet, will the device be available for either?

I will eventually support both sizes, but want to upload an APK to test out the 7-inch to make sure my app will be available for tablets at all.

The documentation is not very clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google says you should have at least one 7 inch and one 10 inch tablet screenshot.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html

Update: I checked on a friend's 10" and my apps with only 7" screenshots show up on Google Play.

Answer (score 8):

Also, you can always fire up an [emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756382/android-tablet-emulator) with your desired divice type and capture screenshots. You don't need to own the physical device to take screenshots. That would not be fun. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Screenshots have nothing to do with it. The settings in your android manifest file control which devices your app is available to. You can set a screen size or density restriction in your manifest.

Look at [supports-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) and [compatible-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) for an idea on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this out and give your answer a check when I see it. =)

Comment: This is a correct answer. Sorry it took so long to mark as correct, Ali.